# How to monitor the windows loopback adapter using sharppcap and npcap?

Tags: c#, winpcap, sharppcap, npcap

I have installed the npcap driver, because I want to monitor the windows loopback adapter. However the loopback adapter is not in the SharpPcap CaptureDeviceList.

I see the loopback adapter in Wireshark and Wireshark is able to monitor the loopback adapter.

What should I do to monitor the loopback adapter using SharpPcap?

Comment: Unfortunately, Winpcap cannot capture loopback packets because theses packets are not bound to any adapter

Comment: @Ksv3n: you're right, WinPcap can't do it. But Npcap *can*.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Ty, it's good to know that

Answer (score 0):

I have helped you create an issue in their GitHub repo here: https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap/issues/15

Please wait for their answers.

### **Update:**

I installed latest Npcap 0.80 with `Install Npcap in WinPcap API-compatible Mode` option checked and ran the `Example01.IfList` example in the SharpPcap repo, and the output is:

```
SharpPcap 4.2.0.0, Example1.IfList.cs

The following devices are available on this machine:
----------------------------------------------------

interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{9ADACD44-ECFF-45E2-BD5E-3491DEBA711F}
Description: Network adapter 'NdisWan Adapter' on local host
Flags: 0



interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{8A300A14-CA5A-4A3C-B52B-7516661B4CDA}
Description: Network adapter 'NdisWan Adapter' on local host
Flags: 0



interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{44DB6B7A-661D-4FA3-925E-6287EA48D3F6}
Description: Network adapter 'NdisWan Adapter' on local host
Flags: 0



interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{F0353155-69D0-4611-AB2A-EE864BE0ADD9}
FriendlyName: Local Area Connection* 19
GatewayAddress: 0.0.0.0
Description: Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host
Addresses:
Addr:      fe80::cd59:f5d:81cb:989d
Netmask:
Broadaddr:

Addresses:
Addr:      fe80::cd59:f5d:81cb:989d
Netmask:
Broadaddr:

Addresses:
Addr:      HW addr: E094678FFF3F

Flags: 0



interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{385F30D0-9166-45D3-BBC6-F1D9C5300AF9}
FriendlyName: Wi-Fi
GatewayAddress: 192.168.0.1
Description: Network adapter 'Microsoft' on local host
Addresses:
Addr:      fe80::eddc:63ca:cf19:aecd
Netmask:
Broadaddr:

Addresses:
Addr:      192.168.0.109
Netmask:   255.255.255.0
Broadaddr: 0.0.0.0

Addresses:
Addr:      HW addr: E094678FFF3E

Flags: 0



interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{1E6769B9-ED4A-454D-A921-EECDA220ADA1}
FriendlyName: Npcap Loopback Adapter
GatewayAddress: 0.0.0.0
Description: Network adapter 'MS NDIS 6.0 LoopBack Driver' on local host
Addresses:
Addr:      fe80::b1cb:57f6:4ebc:6359
Netmask:
Broadaddr:

Addresses:
Addr:      0.0.0.0
Netmask:   255.0.0.0
Broadaddr: 255.255.255.255

Addresses:
Addr:      HW addr: 02004C4F4F50

Flags: 1



Hit 'Enter' to exit...
```

So obviously the last adapter is the `Npcap Loopback Adapter`. I don't know why the user cannot monitor the Npcap Loopback Adapter using SharpPcap. I will reply to him about my feedback in Stackoverflow.

I can think of two possible causes:

1. The user doesn't select the `Support loopback traffic ("Npcap Loopback Adapter" will be created)` option when installing Npcap.
2. The user has WinPcap installed too, and Npcap is installed with `Install Npcap in WinPcap API-compatible Mode` option unchecked. In this way, SharpPcap can only recognize WinPcap and use the original WinPcap DLLs, which doesn't support `Npcap Loopback Adapter` at all.

My suggestions are:

1. Uninstall WinPcap if it is installed.
2. Install latest Npcap 0.80 with `Support loopback traffic ("Npcap Loopback Adapter" will be created)` and `Install Npcap in WinPcap API-compatible Mode` options both checked.

Now the user should be able to see the `Npcap Loopback Adapter` through the SharpPcap interface.

Comment: I did what was suggested and after reinstalling Npcap I do see the loopback adapter in SharpPcap. I think the difference with the first time I installed Npcap is that I now turned on the "WinPcap API-compatible mode". However when I now run SharpPcap Example6 I get the exception "LinkLayer of Null is not implemented" on line 86. PacketDotNet.Packet.ParsePacket raises this exception because e.Packet.LinkLayerType == null. Any idea how to construct a (tcp) packet is this case?

Comment: I tried to change the first (LinkLayer) parameter of the ParsePacket to Loop, Ethernet and Raw but none of these did work (Ethernet gives null TcpPackets and others give an exception)

Comment: The LinkLayer exception is also a bug of SharpPcap. I have reported to them too. Before they fix it, you have a temporary workaround: First uninstall Npcap. Then re-install Npcap, you can see ``Use DLT_NULL as the loopback interface' link layer protocol instead of DLT_EN10MB`` option is checked and gray (can't be changed). Now please uncheck the ``Support loopback traffic ("Npcap Loopback Adapter" will be created)`` option and check it again. You will find the DLT_NULL option can be changed now. Uncheck it and install. (So Loopback option is checked and DLT_NULL option is unchecked)

Comment: Now Npcap will supply Ethernet packets on Npcap Loopback Adapter, and SharpPcap should work.